# compare_faces returns all True values (face_recognition lib)

Tags: python, computer-vision, face-recognition, dlib

I'm trying to automate my recognition script, but stuck with this problem:
when I use `face_recognition.compare_faces()`, I get a result of all `True` values, though it still displays the "unknown" under the bounding box. What could cause such a result? Here's my code.

```
import face_recognition as facerec

j = 1
for file in glob.glob("/home/user/Desktop/registrator/*.npy"):
    unit = "user" + str(j)
    globals()[unit] = np.load(file)
    known_faces.append(globals()[unit])
    known_names.append(unit)
    j += 1

... 

for live_encoding in live_encodings:
            matches = facerec.compare_faces(known_faces, live_encoding, tolerance=0.6)
            name = "unknown"

            if (True == matches):
                first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                name = known_names[first_match_index]

            live_names.append(name)
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more depth?